# Do we have Secondary SiteCollection Administrator in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Do we have Secondary SiteCollection Administrator in SharePoint Online site? Because when I create new Site Collection, I don't see Secondary administrator listed in the form. Also in other posts where adding secondary site administrator using powershell, solution is given as adding to site administrators group only. not as Secondaryowner.
Other posts regarding Secondary Site Admin: [Can I use Set-SPOUser to set an O365 security group as a secondary site collection administrator?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114421/can-i-use-set-spouser-to-set-an-o365-security-group-as-a-secondary-site-collecti/131882#131882)

[Can we set security group as site collection administrator using CSOM in PowerShell in SharePoint Online - Office 365?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131872/can-we-set-security-group-as-site-collection-administrator-using-csom-in-powersh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Office 365 there is no secondary site collection administrator in the sense described here:
*A site collection can have only one primary site collection administrator and one secondary site collection administrator.*
 
From: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631156.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

There is, however, a group of administrators, different from Primary Site Collection Administrator, that can be defined in Sharepoint Admin Center:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-administrators-for-a-site-collection-9a7e46f9-3fc4-4297-955a-82cb292a5be0

The group of administrators can be set after you have created the site collection. You need to go to

- Site Settings>(under Users and Permissions) Site collection administrators or
- SharePoint Admin Center>check the site collection and choose "Owners" from the ribbon:
  [image]

This group corresponds to on premise SharePoint administrators' group:
*You can add as many additional accounts as you want to the SharePoint Site Collection administrators group, (...). All members of the SharePoint Site Collection Administrators group have full administrative permissions to the site collection.*:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631156.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Sidenotes:

1. If you are interested in adding a security group as a Primary Site Collection Owner, it is not possible.
2. There is no such parameter for SPO. It works only with Set-SPSite:

   Set-SPOsite -secondaryowneralias "domain\group"